# "Sensors Off" developer tile removed in Android 12 - Can't open camera

Tags: android, android-sensors, android-12

I recently updated my OnePlus 8t phone to Android 12, I was on Android 11 before, I quickly noticed the new camera and microphone tiles in the notification drawer. I like this new individual tiles for them.

I was previously using a work around solution in Android 11 with the "Sensors Off" tile located in the developer options under 'Quick settings developer tiles'. This disabled the phones camera and other sensors while the tile is on.

I had the tile on as I updated my phone to Android 12, not knowing it would cause an issue, I left the sensors disabled and removed the tile from both the notification drawer and the developer settings!!!

I now can't use my camera in the app (it just won't open) or use the camera in any app (it just displays a black screen, can't even click the shutter button to take a black picture)

Is there anything I can do??! I've already given feedback to the [Android Open Source Project](https://source.android.com/devices/sensors/sensors-off).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't a programming question, its asking for help on a specific build of Android.

Comment: r/androiddev said to post a 'help me' question here instead of on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/) `rule 2`

Comment: That rule is incorrect.  This site is only for programming questions.  This is not  programming question.  Reddit doesn't decide what questions are appropriate here.  They only have the ability to moderate posts on their own forum.

Comment: @GabeSechan Stale quick-tiles after an OS upgrade is still about the tools used.

Comment: @MartinZeitler No, it's not.  An OS isn't a tool used in programming.  If it was about a compiler update breaking things I'd agree.  If he was showing "this specific code broke when I updated the OS" that fits.  Some feature of a phone not working after an OS upgrade is exactly the type of questions we don't want.  Now if he does have specific code that was broken it might be a salvagable question, but as is it should be closed.

Comment: @t0mas I've just found out by chance how to do it ...and can proof it by screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

The actual answer is to enable the tile in the Developer options > Quick settings developer tiles:

[image: Quick settings developer tiles]

Which then permits to flip the switch:

[image: Quick settings developer tiles, in action]

This at least works on a Motorola G100.

Comment: This is how I got the tile in android 11, but they removed the toggle in yhe developer settings in android 12 on my phone (as I stated in my initial question)

Comment: This is not true, as my (only resized) screenshots proof. This may be vendor specific. I've already wondered, why I was able to add the tile back in, despite I couldn't switch it, unless I've enabled it there - your not so stock ROM may have dropped support for that. Try it on an emulator once - and then proceed to the factory reset. This is a lockout situation, where the setting became completely inaccessible.

Comment: There's two options: A) file a bug report with the hardware vendor B) perform a factory reset. Unless they'd add the tile back in or would flip the setting with an update, only option B makes sense.